# Rolling sum then get random int using this rollingsum

Tags: python, pandas

I have this Dataframe:

```
    Date                A
0   2014-11-21 11:00:00 1
1   2014-11-21 11:00:03 2
2   2014-11-21 11:00:04 5
3   2014-11-21 11:00:05 3
4   2014-11-21 11:00:07 9
5   2014-11-21 11:00:08 6
6   2014-11-21 11:00:10 3
7   2014-11-21 11:00:11 1
8   2014-10-24 10:00:55 8
9   2014-10-24 10:00:59 10
```

Im trying to calcultate the rolling sum of a column `A` with a period of 2 seconds.

Let's says this new column is named `rsum`.

After calculating `rsum' column, i want to use it to make another column named`B`.

`B` values are `A` value + random int between -1*rsum and rsum.

Here's my full working code :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import timedelta
from random import seed, randrange
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": ['2014-11-21 11:00:00', '2014-11-21 11:00:03', '2014-11-21 11:00:04', '2014-11-21 11:00:05', '2014-11-21 11:00:07', '2014-11-21 11:00:08', '2014-11-21 11:00:10', '2014-11-21 11:00:11', '2014-10-24 10:00:55', '2014-10-24 10:00:59'], "A":[1, 2, 5, 3, 9, 6, 3,1, 8, 10]})
df
df.Date=pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

df['ind']=df.index
df = df.set_index('Date')

df['rsum']= df.groupby('ind').rolling('2s', closed = 'both').A.sum().reset_index(level=0, drop=True) 
df['B'] = df.apply(lambda x : randrange(-x.rsum, x.rsum), axis=1)
print(df.drop(columns=['ind', 'rsum']).reset_index())
```

Result is :

```
                 Date   A  B
0 2014-11-21 11:00:00   1  0
1 2014-11-21 11:00:03   2  1
2 2014-11-21 11:00:04   5 -5
3 2014-11-21 11:00:05   3  1
4 2014-11-21 11:00:07   9  6
5 2014-11-21 11:00:08   6  2
6 2014-11-21 11:00:10   3  2
7 2014-11-21 11:00:11   1  0
8 2014-10-24 10:00:55   8  0
9 2014-10-24 10:00:59  10 -2
```

My code is actually working, but as im new to Python im sure that's not the most efficient way to achieve this. Because calculating B value isn't vectorized `df['B'] = df.apply(lambda x : randrange(-x.rsum, x.rsum), axis=1).

I have another question what if i have to do this for multiple columns and not only one,  i think the most obvious way to do this is to do a for loop for each column and repeat  `df['B'] = df.apply(lambda x : randrange(-x.rsum, x.rsum), axis=1).` is there any.

What's the most efficient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I benchmarked 4 approaches using both `numpy` and `randrange`

```
%timeit df['B'] = df.apply(lambda x : randrange(-x.rsum, x.rsum), axis=1)
2.06 ms ± 44.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit df['C'] = df.apply(lambda x : np.random.randint(-x.rsum, x.rsum), axis=1)
2.07 ms ± 34.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit df['D'] = df['rsum'].map(lambda x : np.random.randint(-x, x))
340 µs ± 2.39 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

# Winner
%timeit df['E'] = df['rsum'].map(lambda x : randrange(-x, x))
333 µs ± 3.59 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

As you can see `randrange` with map is the `fastest`, you shouldn't use `apply` if the operation is on only one column

Comment: Okay, thank you. What about the multiple column case ? Is there any tip i could use to vectorise this ?

Comment: there are A LOT of variables to consider and it's very situational; however for basic mathematical operations use `apply` for multiple columns

Comment: You mean `map` ?

Comment: `map` -> single column, `apply` -> multicolumn, in other words `apply` is for the dataframe

Comment: I'm not sure `map` is any more vectorized, but it does operate on much less.

Comment: im not sure about the inner workings but the speed difference is quite large, from my benchmark above

Answer (score 1):

The newest developer version of `numpy` could do this out of the box, but since you likely do not have that, what you need is a vectorized version of `np.random.randint`:

```
>>> def randint(x):
...  return np.random.randint(-x, x)
...
>>> np.vectorize(randint)(df.rsum)
array([ 0,  0, -1, -3, -1,  5,  2,  0, -8,  4])
```

where everything is the same up until your `apply`. You can put this in a new column and so forth. You can drop `rsum` as well and just use the previous command output here. Make sure you vectorize only once in real code, so

```
my_rand = np.vectorize(randint)
df['new_col'] = my_rand(df.rsum)
```

In general Pandas plays very nicely with Numpy. I would not use `random` stuff not from Numpy (or Scipy) when using these libraries.